# Mysql 5.6 server via MacPorts won't start

Tags: macos, mysql, macports

I've been happily using MacPorts' `mysql5` and `mysql5-server`.  Now it's time to upgrade.  I followed standard procedure, but the server won't start.

```
sudo port unload mysql5
sudo port install mysql56 mysql56-server mysql_select
sudo port select -set mysql mysql56
sudo port load mysql56-server
```

No errors.  When I run `ps aux | grep sql` I see it's not running.  I tried setting the socket in my.conf and running mysql5_install_db (but that seems specific to the older package).  File permissions look correct.  There's no mysql error log yet.  How do I get this server started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.  Opened LaunchDaemon plist file to see the exact command which would run.  Ran that manually to see the startup output and eventually came up with the solution:

```
sudo mysql_install_db5 --datadir=/opt/local/var/db/mysql56
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /opt/local/var/db/mysql56/
sudo mysql_upgrade
```

If you need help tracking down startup errors, open `Console` and messages containing "mysql".  In my case the process was quickly closing, causing an infinite loop of retries.  To dig deeper, open this file to see how it's launched:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql56-server.plist
```

From there we can see it basically runs

```
/opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=mysql56-server --start-cmd /opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql
```

So at the command line try

```
sudo -u _mysql /opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqld
```

and watch the startup output.

Comment: This worked great for me, I was having the exact same problem. Where is the LaunchDaemon plist file located?

Comment: @m.p.c I edited my answer with more details.

Comment: Be careful with mysql binaries with a "5" as suffix. They belong to the mysql5-server package (the old 5.1.x version!). After mysql_select binaries without suffix are symlinked to the mysql56-server distribution (see "ls -lah /opt/local/bin/mysql*"). Make sure you use these.